# Why am I getting an error when I use `uname` in my .bashrc?

Tags: linux, bash, uname

In my .bashrc I have the following code

```
if [`uname` == "Linux"]; then
    echo "It worked"
else
    echo "It didn't work"
fi
```

But when I source my .bashrc I get the following results

> [Linux: command not found
>
> It didn't work

Strangly, the `[` is not a typo, it is part of the error. If I comment out the if-statement, then the error goes away, so I am pretty sure that it is the source of the error. Plus, if I change the `Linux` to `linux`, then the error changes to lowercase also.

And if I echo uname I get Linux.

To source my .bashrc I have used `source .bashrc` and also have started a new bash session by typing `bash` on the command line terminal.

I didn't think it was that hard to check for the OS type, but I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax for the .bashrc.

I don't see what I am doing wrong, can anyone help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot a space after the square brackets. The first line has to look like this:

```
if [ `uname` == "Linux" ]; then
```

In your version, without the spaces, the `[` and the output of `uname` is concatenated into one executable named `[Linux`, which does not exist in the PATH.

Comment: Stupid me. Thanks I should have caught that.

Comment: +1 for answering the OP's implied question of "why," and not just showing the correct syntax. The only thing I'd change is that Bash is not saying that `[Linux` doesn't exist; it's saying that it's not found in the PATH. Subtle distinction, but possibly important to someone other than the OP.

Comment: @Florian - P.S. thank you for being nice about your answer. I have found on many forums people can be very mean to beginners like me when we make dumb mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

Bash in finicky about spacing. You need spaces in your conditional

```
if [ `uname` == "Linux" ]; then
    echo "It worked"
else
    echo "It didn't work"
fi
```